# Entity Framework Code First ReadOnly Collections

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

As a new to Entity Framework, and already having developed almost all classes with the ReadOnly collections, my question is:

Is there a way to use ReadOnly collections with Code First?

OR

Should ReadOnly collections be used with Code First?

Comment: For reference, there is a newer similar question with some interesting answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191103/entity-framework-read-only-collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not way to use read only collections with EF because even during materialization of entities read from database EF must fill that collection with entities or assign writable collection to your navigation property.

Comment: Thank you. For all I have read (and tried) about Code First that seemed to be the right answer, but I could not find any documentation on this.

Comment: Actually I cannot give you any link now. I will try to search little bit but I 'm not aware of any now.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the new question about documentation since I did not to want to broaden this question: [Documentation on ReadOnly Properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474867/entity-framework-code-first-documentation-on-readonly-properties)

Comment: Then, how do you make Aggregate Roots to enforce the invariants in a Domain-Driven Design approach? This should be possible having EF to fill the "internal state" of the entity and then, the developer could expose it the way he wants.

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework supports ***Read Only Collections*** throught ***[backing fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field)***

There are conventions to folow: field must started with '_'. See field _posts in code bellow.

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    private string _url;

    public string Url
    {
        get { return _url; }
        set { _url = value; }
    }

    //backing field
    private List<Post> _posts;

    public IReadOnlyList<Post> Posts => _posts.AsReadOnly();

}

public class Post{

  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string  Title {get;set;}
  public string Content {get;set;}

}
```