# Do EntityFramework collection properties need a setter

Tags: .net, entity-framework, setter, navigation-properties

The usual approach for modeling 1-n relations with EntityFramwork (Code First) is to use virtual collection properties like:

```
class Project {
  public virtual ICollection<Remark> Remarks { get; set; }
}

class Remark {
  public virtual int ProjectId { get; set; }
  public virtual Project Project {get; set; }
}
```

Since the `Remarks` collection is initially `null`, I take the following approach

```
  private ICollection<Remark> _remarks;
  public virtual ICollection<Remark> {
    get {
      if (_remarks == null)
        _remarks = new List<Remark>();
      return _remark;
    }
    set {
       _remarks = value;
    }
  }
```

in order to use the `Remarks.Add` method on a newly created `Project` object without the need to explicitely set the Property.

Afaik EF internally derives from my class and overwrites the virtual navigation properties to support lazy loading.

My question: Do I need to define the *setter* of a collection property? Does EF require it? I'd rather like to only expose the getter and let the class manage the collection internally.

*Edit* Accidentially I only noticed this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191103/entity-framework-read-only-collections) just after postin mine, so maybe it's just a duplicate ...

Comment: heads up for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2227?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Entity framework can handle private members. You can give the property a private setter:

```
private ICollection<Remark> _remarks;
public virtual ICollection<Remark> Remarks
{
    get { return _remarks ?? (_remarks = new HashSet<Remark>()); }
    private set { _remarks = value; }
}
```

You can even omit the setter altogether.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've seen, EF Core doesn't need a setter either.

You do need `virtual` if you are using lazy-loading. Otherwise you can omit that as well.