# Protect a list from the undesired Add leaving Entity Framework happy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I have an object, say the usual `Order` that have a collection of `LineItem`. To satisfy some business rules I need to have complete control against the list (i.e. nobody can add an element to this list simply using the built in `Add()` method). So I do something like:

```
public class Order {
    private List<LineItem> lineItems {get; set;} 

    public IEnumerable<LineItem> LineItems {
        get { return lineItems.AsReadOnly(); }
    }
}
```

This solution do the job but have a big side effects if other player come into play (e.g. Entity Framework). In fact during the model building, EF expects an ICollection (while I need an IEnumerable):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasMany<LineItem>(e => e.LineItems) // here is the exception: No implicit conversion among IEnumerable and ICollection
            .OtherMappingProperties(); // <-- this don't belong to EF's Fluent API :)
```

**EDIT 1 -**  The solution provided by @Pieter21 avoid the compile time error, since `LineItem` is now a Colection, but I get a runtime exception when somewhere in my code I have something like:

```
return Set.Include(s => s.LineItems)
```

since none have set `lineItems` (none could since is private) so I get a NullPointerException.
Since the Entity configuration and Domain model are in different package the use of `internal` instead of `private` would not resolve the problem unless the use of `InternalsVisibleTo` (but I don't want to spoil the AssemblyInfo.cs of the Domain model with something persistence related)

How to workaround this issue?

PS: The EF configurations and domain model are in different namespaces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework read only collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191103/entity-framework-read-only-collections)

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like:

```
        public ICollection<LineItem> LineItems 
        {
            get 
            { 
                return new ReadOnlyCollection<LineItem>(lineItems); 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: I can't do `return Set.Include(s => s.Items);` since `lineItems` is `null` and I get a NullPonter!

Comment: That's an initialization/constructor problem, not a EF/mapping problem.

Comment: @Pieter21 How would you map `LineItems` and at the same time make EF populate `lineItems`? I don't think this can work.